# Raspbian Jessie SystemD service - How to not depend on Networking

Tags: raspbian, boot, systemd

I am running the latest Raspbian Jessie with every package ( and the kernel ) updated as of 2016-03-18. The majority of my boot time is spent in the Networking service for systemd. Networking works great, but how can I get the login prompt earlier, without waiting for the systemd networking service to do all of it's connection and DHCP negotiation? I'd like the networking service to continue working in the background but not block my other services and allow the login prompt to show sooner. Thank you.

Systemd-analyze:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# systemd-analyze 
Startup finished in 2.010s (kernel) + 34.109s (userspace) = 36.120s
root@raspberrypi:~# systemd-analyze blame
         22.889s networking.service
          7.148s dhcpcd.service
           575ms systemd-logind.service
           388ms triggerhappy.service
           386ms busybox-syslogd.service
           376ms kbd.service
           364ms fake-hwclock.service
           359ms avahi-daemon.service
           337ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           329ms systemd-fsck-root.service
           231ms ntp.service
           224ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           188ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           184ms systemd-modules-load.service
           169ms dev-mqueue.mount
           150ms boot.mount
           139ms home-pi.mount
           106ms systemd-journal-flush.service
            95ms systemd-update-utmp.service
            73ms plymouth-read-write.service
            72ms systemd-random-seed.service
            50ms systemd-sysctl.service
            49ms tmp.mount
            49ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
            42ms rc-local.service
            38ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
            36ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
            34ms systemd-remount-fs.service
            33ms systemd-user-sessions.service
            32ms systemd-udevd.service
            30ms systemd-rfkill@rfkill0.service
            30ms busybox-klogd.service
            30ms sys-kernel-config.mount
            27ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
            26ms plymouth-quit.service
            24ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
            24ms var-tmp.mount
            22ms udev-finish.service
            18ms var-log.mount
            11ms keyboard-setup.service
            11ms systemd-fsck@dev-mmcblk0p1.service
```

Status:

```
● networking.service - LSB: Raise network interfaces.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/networking)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
        /lib/systemd/system/networking.service.d
           └─network-pre.conf
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-03-17 18:17:25 UTC; 18h ago
   CGroup: /system.slice/networking.service
           ├─267 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -D nl80211,wext -C /run/wpa_supplicant
           └─390 dhclient -v -pf /run/dhclient.wlan0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlan0.leases wlan0

Mar 17 18:17:24 raspberrypi networking[168]: DHCPACK from 192.168.0.1
Mar 17 18:17:24 raspberrypi networking[168]: /sbin/dhclient-script: 46: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/samba: cannot create /etc/samba/dhcp.conf.new: Read-only file system
Mar 17 18:17:24 raspberrypi networking[168]: mv: cannot stat '/etc/samba/dhcp.conf.new': No such file or directory
Mar 17 18:17:25 raspberrypi networking[168]: /sbin/resolvconf: 69: /lib/resolvconf/unbound: cannot create /var/cache/unbound/resolvconf_resolvers.conf: Read-only file system
Mar 17 18:17:25 raspberrypi dhclient[282]: bound to 192.168.0.4 -- renewal in 38357 seconds.
Mar 17 18:17:25 raspberrypi networking[168]: bound to 192.168.0.4 -- renewal in 38357 seconds.
Mar 17 18:17:25 raspberrypi networking[168]: ifup: interface wlan0 already configured
Mar 17 18:17:25 raspberrypi networking[168]: done.
Mar 17 18:17:25 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Raise network interfaces..
Mar 18 12:19:16 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[267]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 2c:b0:5d:a8:fc:50 [GTK=CCMP]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option in raspi-config to not wait for network.

Comment: Thank you that works - can you please tell me what it does? Which systems file did it change?